# Could the Jadelle birth control be affecting my breast milk?

Tags: infant, health, safety, breastfeeding

I got the [jadelle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norplant) a week ago today and my second daughter is 4 weeks old. Family Planning told me it was fine to get it, but for the last two days my daughter has had a higher temperature, has been throwing up everything, is really unsettled and not feeding properly. The only thing I can think of that could have any affect is my jadelle.  Family Planning told me would take approximately a week to kick in, which is about now. Is it possible that the implant is having an affect on my daughter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hormonal implant is generally not recommended for breastfeeding women, specifically in the first six weeks. I've only found mixed studies in terms of impact on breastfeeding women ([inconclusive study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3931973), [need further study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12169382), [impact on immunoglobulin](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3936675). Studies are non-existent when the use is before 6 weeks post-partum.

One thing to know is that the steroid has been identified and detected in breastmilk, but there was [no significant impact on infant growth](http://www.rxlist.com/norplant-drug/warnings-precautions.htm).

> Steroids are not considered the contraceptives of first choice for
>   breast-feeding women. Levonorgestrel has been identified in the breast
>   milk. The health of breast-fed infants whose mothers began using the
>   NORPLANT (levonorgestrel implants (unavailable in us)) SYSTEM during
>   the **5th to 7th week postpartum was evaluated**; no significant effects
>   were observed on the growth or development of infants who were
>   followed to 12 months of age. **No data are available on use in
>   breast-feeding mothers earlier than this after parturition**.

[One study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12169382) stood out in indicating that there is a higher incidence of infections:

> Breastfeeding pattern and infants growth, from admission through age 6
>   years, were similar in both groups. In the first year, **breastfed
>   infants in the Norplant group had higher incidence rates (p < 0.05) of
>   mild episodes of respiratory infections (adjusted RR 1.17, CI
>   1.08-1.27), skin conditions (adjusted RR 1.46, CI 1.20-1.79), and eye infections** (unadjusted RR 1.49, CI 1.03-2.18) than the control group.

Your best bet may be to consult actual medical advise to determine what may be causing the change in your daughter. So many things can irritate infants that it really is best left to a pediatrician / qualified medical professionals.